# Write down the matrix of T with respect to the basis $\{1, 1 + x, 1 + x^2, 1+x^3\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

let $V$ be the space of all polynomials in one variable with real coefficients
and of degree less than, or equal to, $3.$ 
Define the linear transformation
$$T(\alpha_0 + \alpha_1x + \alpha_2x^2 +\alpha_3x^3)  = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1(1 + x) + \alpha_2(1 + x)^2 + \alpha_3(1 + x)^3$$

Write down the matrix of T with respect to the basis
$\{1, 1 + x, 1 + x^2, 1 + x^3\}.$

I was trying but I couldn't solve this question.

If anybody help me, I would be very thankful to him or her.

Comment: You don't know the procedure of how to set up the matrix, or you get stuck in calculations while doing it?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Calculate $T(b)$ for every $b\in\lbrace 1,1+x,1+x^2,1+x^3\rbrace$ and expand.

Answer (score 3):

**Procedure**: determine the image of the $i$-th basis vector under the given linear transformation and write this image with respect to the given basis. Its coordinates are the $i$-th column of the transformation matrix. Do this for all basis vectors ($1 \le i \le 4$).

---

E.g. for the *second* basis vector $1+x$, you have $T(1+x) = 1 + (1+x) = 2+x$. Writing this as a linear combination of the given basis vectors, you get:
$$2+x = \color{blue}{1} \cdot 1 + \color{blue}{1} \cdot \left(1 + x\right) +\color{blue}{0} \cdot \left(1 + x^2\right)+\color{blue}{0} \cdot \left(1 + x^3\right)$$
so the coordinate representation of $T(1+x)$ with respect to the given basis is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}\color{blue}{1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0} \end{bmatrix}$$
and this will be the second column of the transformation matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}. & 1 & . & . \\. & 1& . & .  \\ . &0& . & .  \\ . &0 & . & . \end{bmatrix}$$
That's 1/4 of the work. Can you take it from there?

Comment: i was trying but i get T(1+x^2) = 1.1  + 1.(1 +x) + 1.(1+x^2) + 0.(1+x^3).....is it correct@ StackTD

Comment: @lomberlego Careful: $T(1+x^2)=1 + 0\cdot(1 + x) + 1\cdot(1 + x)^2 + 0\cdot(1 + x)^3 = 2+2x+x^2$. Now write this as a linear combination of the basis vectors.